# Use env variable in helper file (Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that looks a bit like this:

File structure

```
- src
  - pages
    - Homepage.js
  - helpers
    - customFetch.js
```

Homepage.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import customFetch from '../helpers/customFetch'

export default function Homepage() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    setInterval(() => {
      customFetch('/my-endpoint').then((result)=> {
        // Do something...
      })
    }, 5000);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      Homepage content here
    </div>
  )
}
```

customFetch.js

```js
export default function customFetch(path) {
  const apiURL = 'https://api.mysite.com'

  // Do something fancy here...

  return fetch(`${apiURL}${path}`)
}
```

What I want to do is to bring `apiURL` from a `.env.*` file instead of hard coding it. How could I do it the Gatsby way? Thanks!

PS.: I know that doing this inside a page is trivial (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) but that's a bit different than what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to set up your environment in your `build` and `develop` command like this (in your `package.json`):

```
"build": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=yourEnvironment gatsby build",
"develop": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=yourEnvironment gatsby develop",
```

The snippet above will get the configuration from `.env.yourEnvironment` file. Then, you need to create your environment file and define your desired variables, such as (`.env.yourEnvironment`):

```
API_URL=https://api.mysite.com
```

Then, in your `gatsby-config.js` (outside `module.exports`) you need to require that environment file:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

According to [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/), this is because:

> Project environment variables that you defined in the .env.* files
>   will NOT be immediately available in your Node.js scripts. To use
>   those variables, use NPM package dotenv to examine the active .env.*
>   file and attach those values. dotenv is already a dependency of
>   Gatsby, so you can require it in your gatsby-config.js or
>   gatsby-node.js like this:

The last step is to get your variable in your component using:

```
  const apiURL = process.env.API_URL
```

In your case:

```
export default function customFetch(path) {
  const apiURL = process.env.API_URL

  // Do something fancy here...

  return fetch(`${apiURL}${path}`)
}
```

That allows you to separate the logic and token and environment variables to implement a multisite (multidomain) project for example.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was actually doing everything you mentioned, just not the "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=yourEnvironment" part :) I have a question for you though: isn't it a little fragile to pass environment variables from one process to another like this? Wouldn't it be better to store the environment, say, in a JSON file that wouldn't be committed (in case it had sensitive data)? Just picking your brain!

Comment: Yes, I could agree with you but, keep in mind that Gatsby is a static site generator and those commands will run only once in the deployment server. Moreover, you should exclude your `.env*` files from your git tracking so you must ignore them because it is there where your tokens, API parameters and so on will be stored. If you have any issues or question please don't hesitate. If not, accept my answer to close the post. Have a nice day @PedroNetto.